# Appending new container on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to learn HTML and Javascript/jQuery. If I have a container which holds a title, an image, a description and a number, then I want to create a new container with the exact same format (except the values will be different), how is this commonly done?

This is an example of the format I'm looking for in each item.

```
    <li>
        <div>
            <div>
                Image Name
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href=URL>
                    <img src='image_url'>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                Description
            </div>
            <div>
                num_comment Comments
            </div>
         </div>
    </li>
```

Do I just create a string and concatenate with the actual values for the image, then add that string to some variable I've saved called html_content, and then set the html value to html_content? Is that the common way of doing this or is there a better way?

**EDIT**

To give a better idea of what I'm currently doing, here's the javascript:

```
    var html1 = '<li><div><div>';
    var html2 = '</div><div><a href="';
    var html3 = '"><img src="';
    var html4 = '"></a></div><div>';
    var html5 = '</div><div>';
    var html6 = '</div></div></li>';


  function render(pics){
    for (var i in pics){
      html = html + html1 + pics[i].name + html2 + pics[i].image_url + html3 + ...
    };
    $('pics').html(html);
  }
```

Comment: If you mean how is this done in a dynamic way then there are many different ways to do so, I personally would not use javascript for this.  I would use PHP, create a loop structure that pulls in images from a directory and the rest of your other data in another way.  Depends on what your application is really.  What kind of a page are these boxes going to be on?  What's going to be inside them?  Will they have set height's and widths??

Comment: Your `render` function doesn't seem to append the generated html content because each time you iterate `pics` array you are assigning new html content thus overwriting the old content. Shouldn't you be concatenating?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you just have to use the append() function to add on to something.

You could do something like...

```
$('select element').append('<li><div>....etc.');
```

and where you want a different value you can use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.clone()` and create a copy of this, then iterate through the cloned object and change what you need:

```
var $objClone = $("li").clone(true);

$objClone.find("*").each(function() {
    //iterates over every element. customize this to find elements you need.
});
```

To change the image source you can do:

```
$objClone.find("img").attr("src", "new/img/here.jpg");
```

Fiddle demoing the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/H9DnA/1/

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to explore some of the JavaScript [templating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_templates) libraries. The essential idea is that you create a template of your markup:

```
<li>
    <div>
        <div>
            {{name}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="{{url}}">
                <img src="{{imageUrl}}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            {{description}}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{comments}}
        </div>
     </div>
</li>
```

Then you merge it against some associated matching object and insert it into your document:

```
{ name: 'Image Name', 
  url: 'http://example.com', 
  imageUrl: 'http://example.com/image.jpg', 
  description: 'Description', 
  comments [ { text: 'Comment' } ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work just fine:

```
$('#button').click(function () {

    var html1 = '<li><div><div>';
    var html2 = '</div><div><a href="';
    var html3 = '"><img src="';
    var html4 = '"></a></div><div>';
    var html5 = '</div><div>';
    var html6 = '</div></div></li>';

    function render(pics){
        for (var i in pics){
            html = html + html1 + pics[i].name + html2 + pics[i].image_url + html3 + ...
            $("ul").append(html);
        }
    }
    // call render
});
```

I didn't do a test run on your code so there might be an error somewhere. My tweak adds this line `$("ul").append(html);` inside your loop

Answer (score 0):

```
function render(pics)
{
    var theList = document.getElementByid("LIST ID");

    for (var i in pics){

      var listItem = document.createElement('li');  // Create new list item

      var nameDiv = document.createElement('div');  // Create name DIV element
      nameDiv.innerHTML = pics[i].name;             // Insert the name in the div

      var img = document.createElement('img');      // Create Img element
      img.setAttribute('src',pics[i].src);          // Assign the src attribute of your img

      var imgDiv = document.createElement('div');   // Create Img Div that contains your img
      imgDiv.appendChild(img);                      // Puts img inside the img DIV container

      var descDiv = document.createElement('div');  // Create Description DIV
      descDiv.innerHTML = pics[i].description;      // Insert your description



      listItem.appendChild(nameDiv);                // Insert all of you DIVs 
      listItem.appendChild(imgDiv);                 // inside your list item 
      listItem.appendChild(descDiv);                // with appropriate order.

      theList.appendChild(listItem);                // Insert the list item inside your list.

    }

}
```